# Clion Remote Pi: undefined reference to wiringPiSetup

Tags: c, cmake, raspberry-pi, clion, wiringpi

I am trying to run a c-program via clion IDE using the wiringPi library. Hello world runs perfectly fine, so I can assure that the connection to the pi was established correctly. However, when I add the wiringPi-Library #include  and run wiringPiSetup(); I get an error message.

In order to solve this problem, I added "-lwiringPi" at Clion/Preferences/Build, Execution, Deployment/CMake/Build options. However, this didn't change anything. Maybe there is something missing in CMakeLists.c but I actually don't know what.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

// Code I want to make running
int main() {
    wiringPiSetup();
    return 0;
}
```

**Error Message:**

====================[ Build | write_morse | Debug-Remote ]======================
/usr/local/bin/cmake --build /tmp/tmp.tL61Mxt6gP/cmake-build-debug-remote --target write_morse -- -j 4
[ 50%] Linking C executable write_morse
CMakeFiles/write_morse.dir/main.c.o: In function `main':
/tmp/tmp.tL61Mxt6gP/main.c:6: undefined reference to`wiringPiSetup'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/write_morse.dir/build.make:83: recipe for target 'write_morse' failed
make[3]: *** [write_morse] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/write_morse.dir/all' failed
make[2]:**  [CMakeFiles/write_morse.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:84: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/write_morse.dir/rule' failed
make[1]:  **[CMakeFiles/write_morse.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'write_morse' failed
make: *** [write_morse] Error 2

**Error Message with -lwiringPi:**

====================[ Build | write_morse | Debug-Remote ]======================
/usr/local/bin/cmake --build /tmp/tmp.tL61Mxt6gP/cmake-build-debug-remote --target write_morse -- -lwiringPi
[ 50%] Linking C executable write_morse
CMakeFiles/write_morse.dir/main.c.o: In function `main':
/tmp/tmp.tL61Mxt6gP/main.c:6: undefined reference to`wiringPiSetup'

**CMakeList.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(write_morse C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(write_morse main.c)
```

Comment: "Maybe there is something missing in `CMakeLists.txt` but I actually don't know what." - It is difficult to guess what is missing in the file which you don't show.

Comment: Just the basic file.